# Export Azure Application Insights with REST API for search term

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-application-insights, appinsights

I have a requirement where I need to search a particular term in App insights and then export this 'report' and send it in the email. Consider this as "report a bug" use case.

So if I search key "xxxxxx123", it should retrieve all matching traces/logs and then export it to either excel or CSV.

So my question is, is it possible with the NuGet package or even with REST API?

I tried looking at this, but couldn't find it helpful,
[dev.applicationinsights.io/apiexplorer](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/apiexplorer/metrics?appId=DEMO_APP&apiKey=DEMO_KEY&metricId=requests%2Fcount)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no nuget package. You can do it by using the [Get query rest api](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/apiexplorer/query?appId=DEMO_APP&apiKey=DEMO_KEY).

Write any query you need in the Query textbox, then in the right side, you can see the generated request. Then you can use c# or other programming language to query the results, as per [this article](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/quickstart).(Note: remember use your real **Application ID** and **API Key**).

Add a screenshot for your reference:

[image]

After fetch the data, you should write your own logic to export it to csv or excel.